# How can I loop through all parent and child elements in an XML field using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

I have the below script which is in a semi-working state. I have been able to successfully retrieve all the parent elements, but I want to cursor through those to get all their children. When I try passing the current parent name to the cursor I get an error stating the value needs to be a literal. There must be a way around this error and I am wondering if it is as simple as an issue with my syntax below. Any guidance would be appreciated :)

```
CREATE TABLE #Parents
(Name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #Parents (Name)
select distinct a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as t
FROM HE_EXTRACT_HISTORY
CROSS APPLY REQUEST_XML.nodes('//*:SignUp/*') AS xx(a)
WHERE ID = 1113

--Cursor through each node and get all child elements

DECLARE @parentName VARCHAR(150)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select * from #parents

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @parentName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

        -- Get Child Elements
        select distinct a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as t
        FROM HE_EXTRACT_HISTORY
        CROSS APPLY REQUEST_XML.nodes('//*:SignUp/@parentName = sql:variable("@parentName")/*') AS xx(a)
        WHERE ID = 1113
        print @parentName

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @parentName 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Please post an input sample and the corresponding desired output

Comment: When it comes to gathering information from a hierarchy, using a CTE (Common Table Expression) is much easier and efficient than a cursor in T-SQL.  Take a look at the following example applying managers and employees in their teams.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to gathering information from a hierarchy, using a CTE (Common Table Expression) is typically much easier and more efficient than a cursor in T-SQL.  Unless you are determined to apply a cursor, take a look at the following link for an alternative approach to addressing your objective.

[Hierarchies with Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions/)

Using the information from your example I tried to apply a hierarchical CTE.  Please note that I'm unable to error check the following, but it should be enough to put you in the ballpark.

```
WITH ParentChild AS
(
-- Get parent
SELECT
    a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as t
FROM HE_EXTRACT_HISTORY
CROSS APPLY REQUEST_XML.nodes('//*:SignUp/*') AS xx(a)
WHERE ID = 1113
GROUP BY a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)')

UNION ALL

-- Get children
SELECT  
    a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as t
FROM HE_EXTRACT_HISTORY eh
CROSS APPLY REQUEST_XML.nodes('//*:SignUp/*') AS xx(a)
INNER JOIN ParentChild pc ON
    a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') = pc.t
WHERE ID = 1113
GROUP BY a.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)')
 )

 SELECT *
 FROM ParentChild
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for the info. I am definitely not a fan of using cursors ad I have never really played with CTEs so this will be fun, Using the code you supplied I receive an error while running it that states 
DISTINCT operator is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'ParentChild'."

Comment: I forgot about the DISTINCT with CTE's.  Removing the DISTINCT and added the GROUP BY at the end of both SELECT statements should resolve that error.  The thing to keep in mind about the CTE is that it is gone after the use of the SELECT * FROM ParentChild at the end.  To verify the results, you can always add the records from ParentChild into a #temp table.